# Variable referring to class members - Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to create a way to apply a prefix to an item which would modify the item's existing stats. For example in the code below I am trying to apply the 'huge' prefix to the 'jar' item. I'd like to make the code reusable so that I could have different prefixes ('fast', 'healthy') that would modify different item stats.

- Is it possible to hold the name of a class member in a variable?

  - If so, is there any reason I shouldn't?
  - If not, what alternatives are there?

```py
class Prefix(object):
    def __init__(self, word, stat, valu):
        self.word = word
        self.stat = stat
        self.valu = valu


class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    def apply_prefix(self, prefix):
        self.prefix.stat += prefix.valu # <-- Here is my issue
        self.name = prefix.word + ' ' + self.name
        # My hope is to make the code reusable for any stat
    def print_stats(self):
        print self.name, self.size


def main():
    jar = Item('jar', 10)
    huge_prefix = Prefix('huge', 'size', 5)
    jar.apply_prefix(huge_prefix)
    jar.print_stats()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `hold the name of a class member`?

Comment: If the item class could have size or speed, I would like the prefix class stat variable to refer to either size or speed. This would allow me to use one line of code instead of a bunch of if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to *dynamically refer* to some attribute.  You do that by using `getattr`.  And if you want to *set* the attribute, well... that's `setattr` :)

```
def apply_prefix(self, prefix):
    target_attr = getattr(self,prefix.stat) #dynamically gets attr
    setattr(self,prefix.stat,target_attr+prefix.valu)
```

As to whether this is the best coding style: it depends.  There are some instances that code is made more clear by use of `getattr`.  Since right now you only have two stats, it seems excessive to need this kind of dynamic attribute referencing, since I could easily do:

```
bogus_prefix = Prefix('huge','bogus',3)
```

Which is a valid `Prefix`, but throws an `AttributeError` when I try to apply it.  That's not the most straightforward thing to debug.

However, there are bonuses to the `getattr` approach: if you add more stats, you don't have to change a bit (haha) of code in `Prefix`.

Other alternatives?  There are *always* options in Python.  :-)

The way *I'd* do it is to make `Prefix` just a `dict` of word:value pairs.  Then `apply_prefix` would loop over the word keys, updating as many values as I wanted in one shot.  It's a similarly dynamic approach, but a bit more scalable.

Comment: This dynamically fetches the correct value but now how can I dynamically assign it to `self.(prefix stat)` so that `jar.size` will equal `15`?

Comment: Edit: Looks like I found the answer just as you commented. Thanks!